# JQuery-UI auto complete not showing required result with the drop down

Tags: java, jquery, json, jquery-ui, jakarta-ee

I have implemented a auto-complete text box using jquery-ui. But it is just appearing tiny rows instead of showing required result. Here is how it looks like :
[image]

**index.jsp:**

```
<body>
    <h1>Hello Auto complete</h1>
    <br> <br> <br>

    <input id="search">
    <input type="hidden" id="search-id">
</body>
```

**filter.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $("#search").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "SearchDB",
                    type: "GET",
                    data: {
                        term: request.term
                    },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data);
                       // console.log(data);
                    }

                });
            }
        });

    });
});
```

**SearchDB servlet:**

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        String term = request.getParameter("term");
        Session session = com.search.connection.HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Product.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.like("name", term + "%"));
        List<Product> proList = criteria.list();
        List<Product> myList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Product product : proList) {
            myList.add(product);
        }
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String result = gson.toJson(myList);
        response.getWriter().write(result);

    }
```

**My json response :**(when I type "c" in my text box)

```
[{"id":5,"name":"COD 4","qnty":12,"dateAdded":"Dec 12, 2015"},{"id":6,"name":"COD 5","qnty":20,"dateAdded":"Oct 28, 2015"},{"id":7,"name":"Cars ","qnty":13,"dateAdded":"Dec 30, 2014"}]
```

**Console out-put looks fine for me as well:**

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add "value" in your json, I replaced "name" with "value":

```
[{"id":5,"value":"COD 4","qnty":12,"dateAdded":"Dec 12, 2015"},{"id":6,"value":"COD 5","qnty":20,"dateAdded":"Oct 28, 2015"},{"id":7,"value":"Cars ","qnty":13,"dateAdded":"Dec 30, 2014"}]
```

Comment: Thanks. :) It gives me the drop-down correctly. But I would like to know the problem with  `name` instead of `value` ??

Comment: @MadushanPerera, This is how Autocomplete works :) If you are not customizing your data to show, autocomplete will pick "value" from your json. As we haven't defined which one to pick from json, "value" is the default one to pick.

Comment: I would be grateful if you can tell me how to customize to pick user define value without  picking default `value` . An also I need to get the `id` to my hidden input . How can  I do that ?

Comment: Have a look here https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data. There is an event "select", you can insert "id" on this event.

Comment: Ok. I will. Thanks again . :)